# How do you stop a div from moving when you use .animate in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to stop a div from moving when I use .animate. I am changing marginTop. I've tried changing the css of the div to position:absolute but it still moves when it animates.

```js
$("#msg1").animate({marginTop: "-"+calc+"px"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Stop these divs moving -->
<input type="text" style="position:absolute;display: block;" 
id="typingData">
<div id="dataSend">Send</div>
```

Comment: Not calling the animate function will make it stop moving. Also in your example there is no element with the id "msg1". Please provide code that reproduces your problem and describe the desired result.

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's `.stop()` function. https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: @LeviCole thanks tried to use .stop() it seems to stop the divs from moving up for a few frames. I am using it on a textbox